# Is there a standard default simple push message JSON for Android?

Tags: android, json

I have written a program to send a simple text message as push to both iOS and Android devices. However, I have been told that I should not bother the users to write their own JSON. So all I ask from the user is to write the body of the message.

In iOS this will be assigned to the `alert` attribute in their JSON. But I see on Android that you can have different variables. So I am looking for the attribute that will always work as the message text. This is my Android message JSON:

```
{
'title':'no title',
'body':'This is the text message!'
}
```

But I am wondering if `body` is a standard tag I can use with any app? Or will it become unavailable if the users connects my program to another app?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard" JSON tag, unless you're referring to some sort of common digest format.

Comment: I know that there is no standard JSON format. My question is whether the `body` attribute will always work in an Android push message.

Comment: You need make a json object of `data{}` in which you can use title and body attributes

Comment: Something like this? https://parse.com/questions/json-push-notification-format-for-web-console-for-android-and-ios

Comment: @Clairvoyant this very format above is currently working and being sent. But I am wondering if it works if another app is used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey where does the body of the text go? I see alert and title.

Comment: As I understand it, "alert" is the body.

Comment: If by "Android push message", you mean Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), GCM messages are only delivered to one app. The app and the server pushing it the messages need to agree on a common JSON structure. Hence, "will always work", implied as meaning across apps, simply does not happen.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I mean GCM. So are you saying that if I use a tag called `alert` as @Robert Harvey recommended in the answer, there are going to be apps that do not support that tag?

Comment: The only app that will receive your GCM message *is your own app*. There are no other apps to consider. All of the other apps using GCM will be receiving messages from *their* servers, not yours, and the JSON structure will be what *their* developers chose. Worry about your own app and your own servers, and let other developers worry about their apps and their servers.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm aware of the things you say. They change from app to app. What I wanted was to reduce complexity for the user so they only write their message and do not bother in structuring the JSON. I want to make my program to work with other future apps as well, so there is no "my app, their app" argument. In iOS if you have a tag called `alert` it will always be the text to your push message. So I am wondering if such tag also exists in android, something like a default tag. And if the answer is a no, I will have to create a JSON editor in my program.

Comment: "I want to make my program to work with other future apps as well" -- there are no "future apps" of relevance, other than ones that you write personally, since your server will only be talking to your apps. "So I am wondering if such tag also exists in android, something like a default tag" -- no. Android developers and their Web server counterparts are welcome to have the JSON be whatever they want it to be, within the payload size limitations of GCM. There is no requirement that the payload have any specific JSON keys.

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe I wasn't completely clear. I am not writing the app! I don't have an app. I have written a program to send push messages to a client's app. Regardless, I assume your answer is "no". Does that mean @Robert Harvey's answer below is not accurate? That `alert` tag may not always work?

Comment: @Pedram: "I have written a program to send push messages to a client's app" -- then you need to talk to the client to ask the client what the JSON should look like. If the client has not written an Android app that is processing GCM messages, then you and the client will have to agree upon what the JSON should look like. "That alert tag may not always work?" -- I have no idea what "work" means. `alert` has no magic meaning in a GCM payload.

Comment: @CommonsWare we are running through circles apparently. appreciate your time but i don't know if you have still understood what i asked. I will try to test the same `alert` tag on another client. If this tag works for other Android apps as well (without us sitting around a negotiation table and deciding what tags they are going to use), then you are basically wrong. Otherwise, all I have to do is to let the user enter the JSON template of their messages. The problem was inherently not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This format should work for both iOS and Android:

```
{
   "alert": "My_Alert_Text",
   "title": "My_Alert_Title",

   "myKey1": "Custom_Value_1",
   "myKey2": "Custom_Value_2",
   ....
   "myKeyN": "Custom_Value_N"
}
```